# phpMyAdmin themes not displaying properly

Tags: phpmyadmin, themes

I have downloaded a theme for phpma but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. The default themes are just fine, but when I download the metro theme it just isn't showing properly.

This is how it looks on my system

[image: Supposed Metro Theme]

I'm just not sure where to go from here. I downloaded and used the phpma from the website. Any pointers would be much appreciated. I'm not sure what part of any confing.inc file you would need to see.

TIA

Here is just under the header, it is not showing any links like it would in the original theme.

[image: No icons showing]

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @LagMaster, I haven't found an answer to this. I have just left it to the default theme. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot more research into this as it was bugging me.  Simply put, there is a conflict with the Metro theme in PHPMyAdmin version 4.x

There is a different metro theme [here (that you can download)](http://hplhu.deviantart.com/art/Metro-Theme-v3-for-phpMyAdmin-4-382030120) that has bug fixes that makes PHPMyAdmin work properly with the metro theme.  Just download the theme from the right hand side of the webpage and install normally.

Comment: Ah yes, I downloaded that one just after your comment. Seems to have a few bugs still, but bearable. There is no logout link and no dropdown either. Oh well, still works

Comment: There is a logout link actually, it is directly to the right of the home link.  What do you mean by no dropdown?

Comment: I have added an extra image to show there are no icons. I was looking at something else when I mentioned dropdown, you can ignore that bit

Comment: Odd, [It does seem to be working for me](http://gyazo.com/24d873d6aee29cb443b5df5126f9877d).  What version of phpmyadmin are you using?

Comment: Will have to see if I can downgrade and try it again